# Knex.js deadlock on multiple unique constraints

Tags: knex.js

Getting a deadlock when creating a table with multiple unique constraints. Here is
My Code:

```
    db.schema.createTable('users', table => {
    table.increments('id')

    table.string('email').unique()
    table.string('phone').unique()
    table.string('instagram').unique()
    table.string('password')
    table.timestamp('createdAt').notNullable()
    table.timestamp('updatedAt').notNullable()
  })
```

The error:

```
Error creating users table Error: alter table `users` add unique `users_instagram_unique`(`instagram`) - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at Packet.asError (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:712:17)
    at Query.execute (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:28:26)
    at Connection.handlePacket (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:417:32)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:75:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/marwanroushdy/Development/July/API/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:82:25)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10) {
  code: 'ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK',
  errno: 1213,
  sqlState: '40001',
  sqlMessage: 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'
}
```